# Showing $(m,n)=(u,v)$ given initial conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on my proofs, and I think this is valid.  Can anyone confirm?

For the initial conditions, we have that there are integers $a,b,c,d,m,n,u,v$ such that 
$$ad-bc=\pm1, u=am+bn, v=cm+dn$$
Now, I can state that suppose $ad>bc$.  Then $ad-bc=1$  Thus we can say that both $a,b$ and $c,d$ are integers such that $(a,b)=(c,d)=1$
$$adu-bcu=u, adv-bcv=v $$
Letting $m=du=-bv, n=-cu=av$  Then
$$(m,n)=(m,m,n,n)=(du,-bv,-cu,av)=(u(d,-c),v(a,-b))=(u,v)$$
We can argue that $bc>ad$ yields the same result.

Is this okay?

EDIT:  I am not sure how to move forward...

Comment: $(m,n)=(m,m,n,n)$ is meaningless, and the next equality isn't true...

Comment: In particular, it is not true that $m=du=-bv$ and and it is not true that $n=-cu=av$.

Comment: Why would $(m,n)=(m,m,n,n)$ be meaningless?  I was just shown that if I have $(a,b,c)$ then I can argue that $(a,b,c)=(a,b,a,c)=((a,b),(a,c))...$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, how should I procede?  I'm not sure how to go from here then if these arguments fail...

Comment: @Thomas Why do you think that $\ (m,n) = (m,m,n,n)\ $ is "meaningless"?

Comment: Hint: If $q$ divides $m$ and $n$, then $q$ divides $u$ and $v$. For the converse, consider for example $d(am+bn)-b(cm+dn)=\pm m$. (You had this.) Forget about $\gt$, it is simpler than that.

Comment: @BillDubuque I was taking it to mean a $2$-tuple is a $4$-tuple, but I forgot about the GCD notation...

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ \text{determinant of}\,\  \left[ \begin{array}{cr} a&\!\! b\\ c & d\end{array}\right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} m & x\\ n & y\end{array}\right] &=& \left[ \begin{array}{cc} u & \bar u\\ v & \bar v\end{array}\right] \\
\Rightarrow\ \  \color{#0a0} D\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! \smash[b]{\underbrace{\color{#0a0}{(my\! -\! nx)}}_{\quad\ \ \large =\,\color{#0a0}{(m,n)}\ {\rm by\ Bezout}}}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! &=& {\color{#c00}u\,\bar  v-\bar u\,\color{#c00} v}\phantom{I^{I^I}}\\ \\
\end{eqnarray}$

Hence we deduce that  $\ \color{#c00}{(u,v)}\mid \color{#0a0}{D\ (m,n)}\ $ since $\,\color{#c00}{(u,v)}\,$ divides the $\rm\color{#c00}{rhs}$ above, so also the $\rm\color{#0a0}{lhs.}$ $ $ **QED**

**Alternatively**, this can also be deduced using Cramer's Rule, e.g. see [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/677518/242) Notice that the question is simply the special case when the determinant $\,D = \pm1.$